# Set all raster values from decimals to integers on OQGIS

Tags: qgis, pixel

[image]

I have a raster map made up of numerous pixels with decimal values. Is it possible to change these values from decimals to integers?

Comment: Do you have access to `Round Raster` tool? It is a recent tool available in the Processing Toolbox > Raster analysis.

Comment: Yes, I have it.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the image into a new one that is using some of the integer data types. You can see the alternatives from
https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#gdal-translate

Select one of `Byte, UInt16, Int16, UInt32, Int32`.